# Newsfeed content ranking algorithm: graph theory, affinity and machine learning

Tags: algorithm, graph, machine-learning

I am looking for an algorithm to replicate or perhaps improve upon a facebook-esque content ranking algorithm. To that end, each individual user's feed should be tailored to him/her through the parameters of affinity, time decay, and content type. What are some good resources / launchpads to reference in order to implement an algorithm for a facebook style personalized content feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a trivial project.  That said, [bishop](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/) is my go-to machine learning book, and [the stanford book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/) is similarly for information retrieval.